# Admob ads stopped working - did iOS14 affect android versioning as well?

Tags: android, ios, admob

I'm not sure why, but my Admob ads stopped showing on both iOS and Android. I thought there would be issues with the iOS 14 release

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios14

but now I do not see any ads on both platforms. Has there been any required update for Android I missed?